# Как ограничить скорость записи диска для ftp?

Tags: html, linux, ftp

Как ограничить скорость записи на  диск для pure-ftp или другими программами?

Comment: что значит "ограничить скорость диска"?

Comment: Ну ограничить скорость записи на диск.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно настроить скорость загрузки/скачивания (Upload/Download).

Загрузка флаг: `-T` и скачивание флаг: `-t`

К примеру ограничим скорость скачивания с сервера до 10 Кб/с:

```
pure-pw usermod HereFtpUserName -t 10 -m
```

Скорость загрузки на сервер:

```
pure-pw usermod HereFtpUserName -T 10 -m
```

Проверить это можно так:

```
pure-pw show HereFtpUserName
```

В результате снижается нагрузка на диск, особенно если пользователей больше одного)

Comment: А если нужно для каждого пользователя ftp?

Comment: Посмотрите в pure-ftpd.conf на UserRatio и UserBandwidth

Comment: Хорошо,спасибо,а как проверить изменилась ли скорость?